# Carrierwave wrong image_url after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave to upload an image from a remote url :

```
 def save

      uid = SecureRandom.uuid

      storedir = "uploads/#{uid}"

      image = Image.new

      image.image.store_dir = storedir

      image.remote_image_url = "a remote url here"

      if image.save!

          respond_to do |format|

              format.js

              format.json { render json: {:saved => "#{image.image_url}", :id => "#{image.id}"} }
          end

      end

  end
```

the returned result is correct :

```
 Object { saved="https://mybucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads/58406672-c227-4cec-a846-04c443e70f33/thumb_yr169-ae2f3bc4-74f4-47ee-950c-2e06756525b9-v2.png",  id="47"}
```

As you can see the image url is this :

```
https://mybucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads/58406672-c227-4cec-a846-04c443e70f33/thumb_yr169-ae2f3bc4-74f4-47ee-950c-2e06756525b9-v2.png
```

and when I go to check the file, it's there in the right folder, but when I go to the Rails Console and look for that record, the result of image_url is wrong :

```
> Rails console
> Image.find(47).image_url
> https://mybucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads/thumb_yr169-ae2f3bc4-74f4-47ee-950c-2e06756525b9-v2.png
```

The uid after /uploads/ is gone!!

any help please!!

**UPDATE**

Looks like carrierwave is go check store_dir in the uploader to show the image url, in my case I override it before saving the image, and I would like to use that custom store_dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that is because CarrierWave, like most similar libraries try to build your url dynamically.

Add this to your ImageUploader

```
#ImageUploader
def uid
  '58406672-c227-4cec-a846-04c443e70f33'
end

def store_dir
  "uploads/#{uid}"
end

#XController
def save
  image = Image.new
  image.remote_image_url = "a remote url here"
  if image.save!
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.json { render json: {:saved => "#{image.image_url}", :id => "#{image.id}"} }
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

Not totally sure of why you'd want to overide the store, but in order to do that, I think you may be better served by storing the additional details on the `images` table as such:

1. Add a column to your `Image` model, which may be the store_uid
2. In your ImageUploader, change your `store_dir` to use your builder or the field name, e.g if the column on Image is `store_uid`, with value: `whatever-uid-has-been-stored-here`, you could do:

   `def store_dir
     # /uploads/whatever-uid-has-been-stored-here
     "uploads/#{model.store_uid}"
   end`

A cleaner approach and one that's often advised is to create another uploader for each kind of images, for consistency within your application

Comment: I updated my question, the uid is generated dynamically so it's different from record to another

Comment: I did a similar approach to what you suggest, I added a column called uid and in the uploader's store_dir I change the value to "uploads/#{model.ui}" so when I save the image it will use the custom store_dir I've set in the controller, and when it retrieve the record it will use the default store_id which is "uploads/#{model.uid}" but I am still wondering if there a better way to do that maybe...

Comment: we think the same way haha, I did exactly the same method! but I am still searching maybe I can find better method

Comment: Not certain it gets better than that. But I'd wait to hear what others think as well though.

Comment: Accepted your question as it seem no one added any idea! Thank you.